# Select correct Asymmetric/SymmetricAlgorithm based on EncryptionMethod node Algorithm attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encryption

Is there a built-in .NET API that can parse the `Algorithm` attribute of an `EncryptionMethod` element in encrypted XML and identify the correct `AsymmetricAlgorithm`/`SymmetricAlgorithm` to use in decrypting the data?

Here is an example encrypted XML snippet that I would decrypt:

```
<xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
  xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
  <xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue>fWDq0kmaii...U9Tng==</xenc:CipherValue>
  </xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
```

I have been using the `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedData` .NET class but didn't see any sub-properties or methods that help parse the URI found in the `Algorithm` attribute and select the appropriate `SymmetricAlgorithm` (in this case, `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged` with a `CipherMode` of `CBC` and a `BlockSize` of `128`).

Is there any such built-in .NET API method that can correctly identify and configure the needed `AsymmmetricAlgorithm`/`SymmetricAlgorithm` from parsing the encrypted XML?

Comment: What does "configure the need asymmetricalgorithm/symmetricalgorithm" mean?  i.e. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I think the following documentation may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh5h3ft3(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I mean configure the algorithm as specified in the URI of the `Algorithm` attribute; in the case of `http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc`, the `CipherMode` property should be set to `CBC` and the `BlockSize` property should be set to `128`. Another valid URI might end with `aes256-cbc` or even `tripledes-cbc`.

Comment: The MSDN URL you provided does contain an algorithm that is kind of what I'm looking for, though it goes from `SymmetricAlgorithm` to URI instead of the other way around. And it only does the `SymmetricAlgorithm` types and not any of the `AsymmetricAlgorithm` types. I just thought .NET must have some built-in API call that would do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using Reflector on the `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml` class, I found reference to a method named `CreateFromName` on the `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig` class. It is almost everything I was looking for. Given a URI for any `SymmetricAlgorithm`, it will construct <strike>and configure</strike> (see my comment below) the algorithm for you. However, it does not work for any URIs indicating an `AsymmetricAlgorithm` used for key transport.

One thing I've found is that for many people's needs, the `EncryptedXml` class can likely do the decrypting of the document for you, so that this step of constructing your own algorithm objects by parsing the URI would be unnecessary. I believe my particular use case may be exceptional, but at least I can now use the same helper class that `EncryptedXml` is using (at least in the case of `SymmetricAlgorithm` used for block encryption/decryption).

Comment: Actually, it appears I may just be getting lucky that it's parsing the name of the algorithm from the URI; however, I'm not as confident it is configuring it correctly.